# RTMPGW streaming to embedded flash player

Tags: flash, streaming

I've been playing around with rtmpgw, and it's streaming from my laptop without any issues via http, and the stream is playing back through vlc using the address http:// myipaddress: 8902 without issue.

However, how can i go about getting JWplayer to play this stream via a browser? When VLC streams via http, it includes a file name (e.g http:// myipaddress: 8902/myfile.flv). However, rtmpgw seems not to give out a filename so I can't connect to it via the JWplayer setup script. Wget in terminal downloads the stream ok and recognises that it's an flv, so I am wondering how JWplayer can do the same?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Dan